# How to know what kind of IR LED a device is using?

Tags: led, infrared

I have a remote from an expensive sound system just decided to go broke on me, and the people who made it decided it was a good idea that sound system can ONLY be controlled by the remote they provided (no physical buttons or switches).I have no means of getting another genuine remote. So i went ahead and make my own.

TLDR: i was able to finish making the replacement remote and working well with all the buttons. The problem is in order for me to able to make this remote work i had to use the IR LED from the old remote. Why ? I also don't know, I made the identical driving circuit for LED but it would not work for any other IR LED that i bought locally. I have tried buying from 3 different local shops and all 3 did not work, they have the same form factor but it only worked with the IR LED from the old remote. This means that if this IR LED fails i have now way of knowing what to replace it with, and I have also no way of knowing if its my circuit thats broken. Coming from experience debugging for days. only for it to work when i swapped the led.

How do i know what type of IR LED i have? I am guessing there is no other way than to get one of those expensive light wavelength sensors. But before buying those i would like to ask maybe you guys know something from experience. What are the common IR wavelengths? should i measure the LED voltage drop if that can give a hint like how different color LED might have different voltage drop?

Comment: Different wavelength of IR LEDs exist. But what IR LEDs you used and how did you connect them? Are you sure they were connected correctly, did they emit any IR at all? You can just use mobile phone camera to see it. Are you sure they were IR LEDs to begin with, instead of similar looking photodiodes that are receivers? I've even managed to use a standard 3mm red LED in an emergency situation and disregarding the poor range it worked just fine.

Comment: There's not very many wavelengths of LED it could be. By an 800, 850, 900 and 950 and see which one works. Absorptive filters on remote receivers are relatively broad so doesn't need to be exact. Could also estimate from the forward voltage but that's a little tricky.

Comment: Usually remote using 940nm LED. May be some special devices using 850 or 740. 740 you may differ, it partially visible. But the rest only by spec.

Comment: On most phones the back camera has an IR blocking filter while the front does not, so only the front camera will see the blinking remote. As for the LED itself, perhaps it was a 'high efficiency' type with a relatively narrow beam while the device is very insensitive?

Comment: @Justme yes i am sure the connection is correct and not reversed. I did this by checking the current on the negative leg of the LED, if the LED was flipped there would be no current on that leg. the supply voltage is 3.3v , the led is capable of handing that reverse voltage.

Comment: @hacktastical ohhh yeah when i tried the front cam now it can be seen, i was using the rear cam and it did not show anything. But this only solidify even more that there is something different with the IR from the remote since the IR LED that i bought did also light up,

Comment: @user263983 It can be visible by a phone camera , just like hacktastical said, are 740 still visible by phone cameras? i guess i should just buy all those wavelengths from somewhere like digikey.

Comment: @user1850479 if im going to buy all wavelengths what is my upper and lower limit be?  750 i guess would be the lower limit as that is visible light, and since i cant see it emitting light, it must be higher than that? Is it possible for it to be in the 1000 - 1200 nm rannge?

Comment: Wavelength above 1000nm unusual and expensive. Small chance it used in remote. 740 is visible by eye, it is on the edge of visible spectrum.